# PROLOG - LCM of couples in list

Tags: prolog, lcm

I want to find the Least Common Multiple (LCM) of couples from a list. But in the following way:

For example if I have this list:

**L1 = [1,2,3,4,5]**.

I want to produce this list:

**L2 = [1,2,6,12,60]**.

I use the first element of L1 as first element of L2 and the rest follow this form:

```
L2[0] = L1[0]
L2[i+1] = lcm( L1[i+1] , L2[i] )
```

Here is what I've done so far, but it doesn't work. Always printing false.

```
%CALL_MAKE----------------------------------------
%Using call_make to append Hd to L2 list

call_make([Hd|Tail], Result) :-
    make_table(Tail, [Hd], Result).

%MAKE_TABLE---------------------------------------
%Using make_table to create the rest L2
    make_table([],Res,Res).
    make_table([Head|Tail], List, Result) :-
        my_last(X, List),
        lcm(Head, X, R),
        append(List, R, Res),
        make_table(Tail, Res, Result).

%last element of a list---------------------------
    my_last(X,[X]).
    my_last(X,[_|L]):- my_last(X, L).

%GCD----------------------------------------------
    gcd(X, 0, X) :- !.
    gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
        H is X rem Y,
        gcd(Y, H, Z).

%LCM----------------------------------------------
    lcm(X,Y,LCM):-
        gcd(X,Y,GCD),
        LCM is X*Y//GCD.
```

I want to run the program and get this:

```
?- call_make([1,2,3,4,5], Result).
Result = [1,2,6,12,60].
```

Comment: Have you tested all the predicates from bottom to top?

Comment: lcm, gcd, my_last, call_make work. | 

make_table doesn't work (if that's what you mean)

Comment: Yes, that's true, thank you very much, I just changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) is taking two lists to concatenate, while here:

```
append(List, R, Res),
```

`R` is a scalar. Change it to

```
append(List, [R], Res),
```

Comment: Works for me: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/lcm%20couples.pl ... hm. Can't share the query... But you can try yourself.

Comment: Indeed. Must be something with my computer then, thank you very much